# Microformats hreview with invisible item

Tags: microformats

I'm implementing the hreview portion of microformats on a site to be indexed by Google.

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=146645

The `item` field of a review feels clunky to me, since I can't imagine why I'd included the name of the item being reviewed inside the review itself.

For example.  If you are on Yelp there is a page about a restaurant.  The name of the restaurant is at the top, but it wouldn't' make sense to repeat the restaurant name also inside each review block.

So I'm wondering if the `item` field is one of the ones that can be invisible to the user and still indexed by google?  Incidentally, I just checked and it looks like Yelp has this field with a `display: none;` to the user.

Can anyone verify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have some reason to believe there are fields that can't be hidden and still indexed by Google? It seems likely to me that Google will index all hidden fields, just because I doubt it's worth checking for them. But I'm not sure about that.

Hiding fields isn't recommended for microformats. A core idea behind microformats is you should be presenting the same content to both computers and humans. If the content isn't anywhere on the page, that violates that idea. If it's somewhere else on the page, which is often the case for reviews, you can use the [include pattern](http://microformats.org/wiki/include-pattern).

Comment: Yep they mention it here on under non-visible content: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=146897

The include pattern looks perfect.  Actually, on second look that is what Yelp is using.  Thanks!  Accepted this answer.