# What is the semantically correct way to break these lines?

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

I've got the following footer for a project I'm working on:

```
<footer>
  License: <a href="#">Creative Commons BY</a>
  Email: <a href="mailto:#">email@mail.com</a>
  Telephone: <a href="tel:#">0123456789</a>
</footer>
```

For this footer I want each link (and their prefixes) to be displayed on a separate line, and I would like to do it as semantically valid as possible, without adding unneccesary markup.

I've already considered:

- The `<br>` tag, but it is only considered semantic in poetry (or similar content where the line-break is an inherent part of the information, so I cannot use that to break the lines (see this question: [<br> tag semantic alternative usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552978/br-tag-semantic-alternative-usage))
- Using an `ul`, but it isn't really a list, so wrapping it in an `ul` also isn't really a valid option.
- Using fixed widths, but I would really like to find a dynamic solution.
- Surrounding each line with a `<p>`, which seems a bit overdone, because it isn't really paragraphs, but single lines that I'm wrapping.

What would be the best way to break these lines in a semantically sensible way, without adding extra markup?

Comment: um thats a list, so <ul> all the way IMHO, <br> should not be used, and why not add any more markup, few lines of css and your good to go

Comment: I think the 'no extra markup` requirement is a bit overkill. There's nothing semantic about your markup, and you can't make it semantic without, well, adding some semantic mishmash. I think, some microformat is the way to go here. Look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359440/what-is-the-most-semantic-way-to-display-a-street-address-in-html

Comment: @shakurov, Why isn't my markup semantic? I see that in the article you suggested the use of `<address>` is recommended, but what about the license information?

Comment: @shakurov, and maybe I should have said no extra *unsemantic* markup.

Comment: Why isn't that semantic? Because `<footer>` doesn't really say: 'This is where the address info is presented'. As for the license, there's the `rel="license"` attribute (http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-license ).

Comment: @shakurov, I see that if I markup my contact information as a vcard I should include a full name (.fn). Does it matter if I include it in the html, but set it to `display:none` with css? Will it still serve its purpose as an hcard (so for example, could it still potentially be used as a rich snippet by google)?

Comment: Yes, it will. It's not recommended, though. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750836/microformats-hreview-with-invisible-item).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

talking about semantic, this could be a good usecase for  `<address>` if the contact information provided is related to the document (I may suppose, since I see a license information included<sup>1</sup>): see http://html5doctor.com/the-address-element/ for further reference about it.

(If not, the same page on html5doctor is suggesting to simply use a pararaph with the [hcard microformat](http://html5doctor.com/microformats/#hcard) using `<br>` where it's necessary)

So in the first scenario I would go with

```
<footer>
    <p>
       License: <a href="#" rel="license">Creative Commons BY</a>
    </p>
    <address>
        Email: <a href="mailto:#">email@mail.com</a>
        Telephone: <a href="tel:#">0123456789</a>
    </address>
</footer>
```

and

```
footer p { margin: 0; }

footer address {
   font-style: normal; /* just because of default browser style */
}

footer address a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

see jsbin example: http://jsbin.com/ajohur/1/edit

---

<sup>(1)</sup> *Edit* — as pointed out by @unor, the information license should probably stay outside the `address` element, so I wrapped it in a paragraph.

Comment: The license information should not be part of `address`, which may 
*only* contain contact information for the page resp. the parent `article`.

Comment: since address may contain a link to the document author I think it could also contain a link to the document license, anyway yours is a good point about this field.

Comment: For the licensing statement you could use the [`small` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-small-element) (instead the `p`, or if a containing block element is needed, `div`>`small`). I'd still use a `dl` for the contact details (or 2 `div` elements alternatively). Another possibility would be to use one `dl` for everything and add two `address` elements inside of this list.

Answer (score 7):

I see that as a *list*. 
And then the `<ul>` tag can be appropriate.

Maybe even better you can view it as a *list of definitions*, then `<dl><dt>` is appropriate.

Example:

```
<dl>
    <dt>License:</dt>
    <dd><a href="#">Creative Commons BY</a></dd>
    etc.
</dl>
```

To have it on separate lines, just set the dts to `float:left`.

Answer (score 3):

> [...] semantically sensible way, without adding extra markup?

I doubt that you can. Personally i would use a Definition List for this.

```
<dl>
    <dt>License:</dt>
    <dd><a href="#">Creative Commons BY</a></dd>
    <dt>Email:</dt>
    <dd><a href="mailto:#">email@mail.com</a></dd>
    <dt>Telephone:</dt>
    <dd><a href="tel:#">0123456789</a></dd>
</dl>
```

To make them appear as three lines you could float the DT elements left, for instance.

```
dt {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/2nbfg/

The plus side of this is you get a lot more flexibility when it comes to styling it later on. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/2nbfg/1/ for an alternative way of styling it.

See http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/definition/ for more information.

Answer (score 1):

So, *whitout adding extra markup* as you ask, there's only one solution, using pseudoelements for the link element and setting this as a block element:

```
footer a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

But for me, this is not very semantic because you should wrap that content is something else.

Answer (score 1):

I see that semantically as a <dl>.

Answer (score -2):

With CSS you could probably solve this problem:

```
footer > a:before{
  content: "<br/>"
}
```

Comment: you cannot inject markup via content property. At most you may literally write `<br/>` as a text